# How to access and mount Amazon public dataset to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon AWS. I want to access the Google Books Ngrams dataset. The size is about 2.2 TB. Available at: s3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/

Since the data is big, I cannot really download it to my computer.
(1) How can I just examine part of the data? For example, download or examine online 10MB of the big file.
(2) How can I create snapshot so that I can use Amazon EC2 to analyze the dat? In order to create a public data set volume from a snapshot, I need to find the snapshot ID for that data set. But I cannot not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes, you can use AWS CLI or S3DistCP to copy part of the data.
(2) That data is on S3, so you won't have a snapshot as you would on EBS data sets.

I'd recommend you take this lab to understand how to process this data set: https://run.qwiklab.com/focuses/preview/1161?locale=en

Comment: This is not a free lab (1 token = 30 USD), but if you'd like i can send you a free token code, DM @jmfaerman on twitter.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it! I have just tweeted to you.

Comment: I finished the free lab. Thank you! May I ask you a question? I uploaded input.txt on my s3 bucket, and put the mapper.py and reducer.py into the same folder of the s3 bucket. I want to access random line in the input.txt in the reducer.py. i.e line1 = linecache.getlines('/path/input.txt',1). However, even if I put them in the same folder and use os.path.realpath to get the path of input.txt, the reducer stage is failed. In my local machine, it works well. So it's possible the location of input.txt is not the same as the reducer.py, even they are in the same s3 folder. Thank you!

Comment: You should not fetch lines in your reducer directly, as they are going to be "pushed" to your app.

Comment: I understand that the input txt file will first go through the mapper, after sort by system, it will go through the reducer. However, in order to save space, the output of my mapper function lose information, i.e. only contains the index of each line. Thus, in reducer when I want to get the original line given the index, I need have access to the original input.txt file. This works well in my local machine with single node hadoop. But it failed when I use mapreduce service in AWS. So my guess is that os.path.realpath('input.txt') does not really get this file.

Comment: That sounds right if the file is being streamed from S3